# Php form not showing

Tags: php, xampp

Here's the isue. I have a php form saved as "form.php"
I'm new to php. I'm using XAMPP as my server, and I have Apache and Mysql running.

I'm using Sublime Text editor and I have a folder directory named "me" with a php file in the folder "me"

Now I'm trying to open the file in the browser, and I navigate it like : http://localhost/form.php.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong on the server side. If anyone could help, I'd appreciate it. 
I can't post any images, because I'm new to this site.

This is the error message I got:

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404
>
> localhost
>   Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.5.24

Comment: can you show the folder directory? with xampp you want the form.php to be inside of xampps htdocs folder to show on localhost

Comment: Where have you placed the form.php file?

Answer (score 2):

As you are using xampp, all the php files that you need to run must be placed within the htdocs folder:

[image]

Comment: I've just put the file in htdocs and it's still not coming up.

Comment: When you simply type in 'localhost', it should really display the directories inside your htdocs folder. Does that happen? If not, check which port apache is listening to.

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, your 'form.php' file is within the 'me' folder inside htdocs, right? If so, the URL you requested is incorrect. It should be

http://localhost/me/form.php

instead of http://localhost/form.php.

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the `form.php` in your `C:\XAMPP\htdocs` folder and make sure that the Apache Server is listening on the right folder.

Answer (score 0):

Put the folder 'me' in htdocs and the url should be localhost/me/form.php
Alternatively place the form.php file directly into htdocs and the url should be localhost/form.php